# Loading uppy with Rails 7 and stimulus and importmaps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs, hotwire-rails, import-maps, uppy

Is it doable to load [Uppy](https://uppy.io) into a vanilla Rails app via the Rails 7 importmaps?

If you end up pinning `@uppy/core`, you get a lot of dependencies added to your `importmap` file:

```
bin/importmap pin @uppy/core
```

...but when you try to access it via a Stimulus controller like:

```
import Uppy from '@uppy/core';
```

You get a variety of not-so-helpful errors.

Safari shows:

```
syntaxerror: Importing binding name 'default' cannot be resolved by star export entries.
```

And Chrome has a few different responses:

```
SyntaxError: The requested module 'classnames' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

(I've also seen this be a problem for `mime-match` instead of `classnames`.

I'm a bit over my head in terms of debugging this- it's tricky to see where the issue might stem from. Is this a "can't really use the Rails 7 importmaps" type of answer?

Comment: Please share more hints if you will figure out something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this has to do with different import styles supported in different envs.  The maintainers at jspm and importmap-rails have been encouraging users to file issues or fixes with dependencies.  e.g.

- https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails/issues/87
- https://github.com/jspm/project/issues/93

I was able to reproduce the `Failed to register controller: uppy (controllers/uppy_controller) SyntaxError: The requested module 'mime-match' does not provide an export named 'default'` issue you saw when using unpkg.

JSPM doesn't seem to have the issue and I think does a bit more to smooth these out.  You may want to try switching by using the `--from jspm` flag. Though, I believe that's the default.

```bash
❯ ./bin/importmap pin @uppy/core @uppy/drag-drop --from jspm
```

That was enough for me to get a basic controller to load Uppy and its drag-drop plugin:

```js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
import { Uppy } from "@uppy/core"
import { default as DragDrop }  from "@uppy/drag-drop"

// Connects to data-controller="uppy"
export default class extends Controller {
  connect() {
    const uppy = new Uppy({ })
      .use(DragDrop, {
        target: "#drag-drop"
      })
    window.uppy = uppy;
```

I didn't experiment further.  There may be more needed.

Comment: Thanks so much! That does indeed work (although @uppy/dashboard doesn't work, but I think I can get by with drag-drop instead). Really, really appreciate it!